# Unity3D: Photon syncing physics events

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, physics, multiplayer, photon

I'm making a billiard game and I wanna implement multiplayer in it. Since updating the movement in every frame is inefficient and laggy, I thought I could remake the events in game happen in all clients but for some reason they differ from one another.

The direction that the ball launches is correct but it starts to differ for different users when it collides with other balls(if it collides only with the wall it's fine). Technically this shouldn't happen IMO.

This is the code I use to add force to the player ball:

I use this to launch the player ball

```
photonView.RPC("FireBall", PhotonTargets.All, storedDirection, power);
```

This is the function that adds the force to the player ball.

```
[PunRPC]
    public void FireBall(Vector3 stordDir , float poww)
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(stordDir.normalized * poww, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
```

I use this function to get the desired direction of the player.

```
public void UpdateStickPosition()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        { 
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)  
            {
                storedDirection = hit.point - transform.position;
            }
        }

    }
```

I appreciate all help given, don't hesitate to ask me any questions.

Comment: Physics simulation used in Unity is not deterministic. You can't expect same results on different clients. That's why you need to simulate on single client only (with help of Rigidbody.isKinematic property) and send results to others. See PUN DemoBoxes for details.

Answer (score 1):

Unitys physics engine is not deterministic (ie. the results aren’t always the same on all computers) - the actual positions of the objects may go out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the ball as a networked object using photons API. I think it should sync its properties across all the players if you do that, including any position/physics change.

Sample Code:
"photonNetwork.Instantiate(PrefabName,transform.position,transform.rotation,0);"

Check out their manual.
https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/pun-intro

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others